# Google Analytics goal on submit form

Tags: google-analytics

I'm trying to use '_trackEvent' on form submission, but I'm not getting any results. I have inserted the call into a form validation script. Have I misunderstood how to implement this?

```
$(".form-arrange-visit").validate({
submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("Thank you for your message. We'll be in touch to confirm your visit!")
        form.submit();
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Goals', 'Click-Button']);

    },
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        },<snip>
```

There is already an AdWords event attached to the form onsubmit; would this affect anything?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Events will not show up right away in your standard reports (you'll need to wait at least 24 hours for that), but you can still check in Real-Time reports to see any immediate hits.

Comment: Thanks, I have waited several days.